# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am attempting to add a `ScrollView` to my view so users can scroll down however I get the error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" From what I understand that occurs when 10 or more elements are present in a view, however I have less than 10.

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment: .center){
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Your Favorite Shots")
                        .font(.system(size: 29, weight: .bold))
                    
                    Text("125 Shots")
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular))
                        .opacity(0.5)   
                }

                Image("profile")
                    .resizable()                    
 
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 1.05, height: 100, alignment: .top)

            ScrollView{
            //ERROR IS HERE
                Text("test")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI's error messages are sometimes misleading. The problem is actually here:

```
}.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 1.05, height: 100, alignment: .top)
```

`UIScreen` has no property called `screenWidth`. Instead, use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`.

```
}.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.05, height: 100, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: I have created an extension for UIScreen which reflects ‘screenWidth’ to ‘UIScreen.main.bounds.width’

Comment: @user302975 hmm ok then. But that was the only error that came up. Do you have any other code inside `ScrollView{}` besides `Text("test")`?

Comment: Any code I put inside of the ScrollView results in the error. Even an empty ScrollView will return the error as well.

Comment: @user302975 search your project (`Command` + `Shift` + `F`) for the word "ScrollView". You might have defined your own custom struct/class with the same name.